# How to remove world-read/write permissions from android application's files and folders programmatically?

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, directory-permissions

I'm trying to get a security certificate for my application and the evaluators told that I need to change the permission of my application folder to not world-read/write.

I have googled the problem for days but I have not found any logical solution for it. For the example one of the proposed methods was to run "chmod(destinationfile, 0644)" but it needs root permission to run.

Is there any other way to do it programmatically? 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: The permissions of your app folder are set automatically and are set correctly.  You shouldn't be changing it at all.  By default, and Android app is set up so only the app itself, or other apps signed with the same key, can access its folders.

Comment: That's right @GabeSechan. But the evaluators are saying that when they rooted the phone they could find the folders with this permission. I told them that when you make a phone rooted anything is possible, but they didn't accept it!

Comment: If they got the phone there is nothing you can do. Root has super user. They can see and write every file on the device. They need to either accept that, or not keep the data on device